# Cannot checklist checkbox on view laravel

Tags: laravel

Hello everybody i have a simple problem, i cannot checklist my view on laravel

```
{!! Form::checkbox("permissions[]", $perm->name, $per_found, ['id' => 'basic_checkbox_{{$perm->id}}', 'class' =>'chk-col-green' ], isset($options) ? $options : []) !!} 

<label for="basic_checkbox_{{$perm->id}}" class="{{ str_contains($perm->name, 'delete') ? 'text-danger' : '' }}" >{{$perm->name}}</label>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDX9q.png)

Comment: your question is not complete, add some details

Comment: please ask with detail

Comment: @SupunPraneeth,,  cannot click my checkbox

Comment: I believe this isn't related to Laravel, check your CSS styles especially z-index.

Comment: can we see the generated html ? (in chrome right click on the checkbox->inspect->copy the html tag)

Comment: <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="demo-checkbox">
                                    
                                    
                                    <input id="basic_checkbox_<?php echo e($perm->id); ?>" class="chk-col-green" checked="checked" name="permissions[]" type="checkbox" value="add_users"> 
                   
                                    <label for="basic_checkbox_2" class="">add_users</label>
                                   
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>

Comment: if that is the generated html your php is not executing

Answer (score 0):

Really your question is not clear to me also. According to your question I think You want to show a few check boxes to get inputs. In this point of view I am showing an example. In my project I have a language table with different languages. At my controller I just get the languages and pass the array/collection to the view page. At view page simply parse the array with a loop. Code is as follow:

**In controller:**

```
$languages = Language::orderBy('name','asc')->get();
```

**In view:**

```
@foreach($languages as $language)
{{ Form::checkbox('language[]',$language->id,null,['id'=>'language') }}&nbsp;                 {{$language->name}}
 @endforeach
```

Comment: how to change laravel blade {!! Form :: checkbox ("so it can be used like ordinary html ??  <label class="{{ str_contains($perm->name, 'delete') ? 'text-danger' : '' }}">
                                    {!! Form::checkbox("permissions[]", $perm->name, $per_found, isset($options) ? $options : []) !!} {{ $perm->name }}
                                </label>